# No module named 'xlrd' or Missing optional dependency 'xlrd' when read .xls file

Tags: pandas, excel, xls, xlrd

Hi I was using pandas to read an .xls file, since it's the old version Excel file, I specified the `engine = "xlrd"`. However it says  ***Missing optional dependency 'xlrd'*** or ***No module named 'xlrd'*** when I was trying to import it. I looked through all the method on the website, it still does not work.

Some methods I've tried:

1. `which python` -> its under `../.../venv/bin/python`
2. `pip3 install xlrd` or `pip install xlrd` or `conda install xlrd` it shows `Requirement already satisfied`
3. `pip install --upgrade xlrd` -----> `Requirement already satisfied`
4. `pip list` ---> it clearly shows package `xlrd` and the version is `2.0.1`
5. I tried restart the kernel and restart the VScode and even reactivate my venv. Still `Missing optional dependency 'xlrd'` when I tried to use pd.read or `No module named 'xlrd'` when I tried to import this module.

Can any one help me on that how to properly use the `xlrd` module or `xlrd` engine... to get that .xls file read.

Thanks!

Comment: I figured out that if you are using Jupyter in vscode, you have to cmd+ship+p select the venv as your Jupyter kernel.